# Passing data directly between different sessions. Possible?

Tags: php, session

Maybe stupid question but its still interesting for me. Is it possible to transfer some data between different sessions? Can I add some variable into another user's `$_SESSION` directly? Something like this abstract code:

`$notMySession = getSessionById('123'); $notMySession['kindaInfo'] = 'something'`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No directly you cannot transfer session data from one session to another session. That is what the session is made for.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Each user has its own session, which PHP will use when it *speaks* to that specific user. That means that each session is isolated from one another.

Since the session is not stored on the users computer, there might be a way to reach the session files from your code and directly modify the files. But that doesn't sound like a particularly sane thing to do.